# XSL FO: Text spanning multiple cells in a table

Tags: xsl-fo

Is there a way to have a contents (text) of a cell span across multiple rows—being properly hyphenated—and have borders between the rows be persisted in the resulted PDFs? Here's a sample resulting table I need to get:

[image]

I know there's a table property `number-rows-spanned` but it isn't helpful as it doesn't keep the borders between adjacent cells.

I'm using Apache FOP 1.0.